# Install official Nvidia drivers, or are Ubuntu 17.04 drivers sufficient?

Tags: nvidia, 17.04, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce

On a laptop that has an Nvidia card (GeForce 940MX), is it necessary/preferable to install the official Nvidia drivers? Or do the ones that ship with Ubuntu suffice?

Comment: What do you call "official Nvidia drivers" and what is supposed to be "shipped with Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not abhorrent to you to have closed-source, proprietary software on your system, you'll surely get better performance and compatibility (with games, for instance) by installing the current nVidia driver than using the open-source Nouveau replacement driver.

That said, the nVidia drivers (albeit not always the bleeding-edge version; rather versions that have met standards for stability) are available through the Canonical repositories and can be installed with Driver Manager, from System Settings, without even needing to use the package manager.  You could reasonably claim that the nVidia drivers "ship with Ubuntu".

Comment: That's the question I'm wondering about: installing the drivers via Driver Manager vs downloading them from Nvidia's website.

Comment: Use driver manager.  Far easier, and you get a driver version that's been tested by the repo maintainers.